# Models in multiple applications

Tags: django, model

my question is this:Can I split my database-scheema in several Applications? if so, how do I tell makemigrations that model.py run first? I dont want to have problems with foreign keys between models.

app1

---

```
model.py
```

app2

---

```
model.py
```

Comment: Every changes will detect when makemigrations...! What is questioning ?

Comment: order, because if makemigration begins by incorrect application will have problems with foreign keys, sorry, I'm new in django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `app2` [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) with `app1` then  the resulting migration will contain a dependency on a migration in `app1`.

> This means that when you run the migrations, the `app1` migration runs first and creates the table the `ForeignKey` references, and then the migration that makes the ForeignKey column runs afterwards and creates the constraint.

For more information  [`Dependencies`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#dependencies)